# Docker in AWS - Multiple Elastic Network Interfaces

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, routing, docker

I have a docker container running web server that’s listening on port 80 (jenkins/jenkins:lts)

I have 2x interfaces on the host, **one is intended to be dedicated to the container only (once this is working it will be locked down only to allow HTTP/HTTPS**

**Here is the NIC Config on the instance (This is AWS so they are Elastic Network Interfaces):**

- Gateway: 10.10.20.1
- eth0 ip 10.10.20.200
- eth1 ip 10.10.20.111

**Route configuration, since this is asymmetric routing:**

- ip route add default via 10.10.20.1 dev eth0 tab 1
- ip route add default via 10.10.20.1 dev eth1 tab 2
- ip rule add from 10.10.20.111/32 tab 2 priority 500
- ip rule add from 10.10.20.200/32 tab 1 priority 600

Here is some outputs after the above route rules are set:

```
root@docker01:/home/ubuntu#ip route show tab 1 
default via 10.10.20.1 dev eth0 

root@docker01:/home/ubuntu# ip route show tab 2 
default via 10.10.20.1 dev eth1 

root@docker01:/home/ubuntu# ip rule 
0:  from all lookup local 
500:    from 10.10.20.111 lookup 2 
600:    from 10.10.20.200 lookup 1 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

> Docker container is listening on 0.0.0.0:80

**While attempting to access, here are the results:**

- http://10.10.20.200 — WORKS (Loads Jenkins interface)
- http://10.10.20.111 — DOES NOT WORK
- ping 10.10.20.200 — WORKS
- ping 10.10.20.111 — WORKS
- ssh 10.10.20.200 — WORKS
- ssh 10.10.20.111 — WORKS

> Since the ping and ssh works, I have a feeling this has something to
>   do with docker specifically.

**Here is the “docker ps” output for the ports:**

```
0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp
```

**Things I have checked:**

- Firewalls/Security Groups— both ENI’s allow port 80 and ICMP and everything allows unrestricted outbound. There are no Iptables rules other than what docker creates automatically
- Running the container with an explicit listen IP (example: -p 10.10.20.111:80:80) which made no difference, however it obviously killed the ability to access it via the other address.
- netstat shows port 80 open and listening globally

Comment: did you have any success with this?